# Handling error no 1329 and 1904(no data processed and unknown thread)

Tags: mysql

> I have a procedure which kills the sleeping threads inside a event scheduler .
>     It works fine but sometime it  throws warnings
>       like no rows processed, no data fetched, zero row fetched(error no 1329), also some time it shows, unknown 
>       thread(error no 1904). even though I am handling it in the code. For 1904 error  after the 
>       cursor fetches all the IDs, while processing some thread may be missing so it throws that error.
>       I am using MYSQL DB

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `kill_thread`()
BEGIN
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE XID bigint(4);  
DECLARE Sleep_Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID
  FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST P
WHERE P.COMMAND='Sleep' AND P.TIME >20;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

OPEN Sleep_Cur;
select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;
the_loop: LOOP

FETCH Sleep_Cur
INTO XID;

IF no_more_rows THEN
    CLOSE Sleep_Cur;
    LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;

SET @slp_sql= CONCAT("KILL ",XID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @slp_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP the_loop;

END
```

> Please suggest the possible fix for the code, as it is logging to the log file.
>         Thanks